# Не получается создать папки

Tags: java, spring

Нужно сохранить файл в папки, при отсутствии указанных папок необходимо их создать. Путь к папкам имеет такой вид "`uploads/{year}/{month}/{day}/{filename}`"
Вот такой костыль у меня

```
public static String uploadingFileToAPI2(String url, String fileName) {
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.now();
        File theDir = new File("uploads/" + ldt.getYear() + "/" + ldt.getMonth() + "/" + ldt.getDayOfWeek());
        try (InputStream in = URI.create(url).toURL().openStream()) {
            if (!theDir.exists()) {
                theDir.mkdir();
                Files.copy(in, Paths.get(theDir + "/" + fileName));
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Вопрос в том что у меня не получается создать папки, вызываю метод получаю исключение - `java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: uploads\2022\JANUARY\THURSDAY\dog.jpg`

Comment: Безотносительно вопроса, а вы уверены что у вас должно быть в пути `THURSDAY`, а не `27`?

Comment: нужно ldt.getDate() вместо ldt.getDayOfWeek(), потому что требуется число, а не день недели.

Comment: в какой строке исключение?

Comment: исключение в этой строке  Files.copy(in, Paths.get(theDir + "/" + fileName));

Answer (score 0):

Решил: нужно использовать другой метод. Для coздaния кaтaлoгa, a тaкжe вceх poдитeльcких кaтaлoгoв, пpeднaзнaчeн meтoд `.mkdirs()`;